# How do I compare R Markdown outputs with a previous version?

Tags: r, r-markdown

I have a large R Markdown file with many different outputs. The dataset is still being collected, and I often reknit the file to get an update including the most recent data. I would like to automatically see what has changed from the last time without needing to page through the entire output.

A) Is there an easier strategy than writing code to extract all the values from the output and formatting a side-by-side presentation myself?

B) The output includes several figures. I would like to compare these as well, but I would be happy with a solution that only compares numbers.

C) I would also be satisfied with a function or package that saves a defined subset of variables and lets me compare them to the values of variables saved with the same name in the past.

Comment: There are some "latex-diff" types of tools, though they don't always get things right. You will probably have better luck with output to markdown and using `diff`. A stronger solution might even use `git` and some auto-commit magic so that you can see the output progress through the life of your project.

Comment: Though much more than r-markdown, there is [`shinytest`](https://shiny.rstudio.com/articles/shinytest.html) that provides some strong indicators.